# How to check all radio buttons based on database values?

Tags: mysql, radio-button

I'm busy making a small comment system. I want users to be able to give ratings, besides giving comments, and right now i'm storing these rating values (that come from radio buttons) in the database. However, when I try to populate radio buttons with rating values for each comment from the database, the following script only checks the radio button that corresponds to the last value in the database.

```
    <?php 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id_post = '$id_post'") or die(mysql_error());;
while($affcom = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){ 
    $name = $affcom['name'];
    $email = $affcom['email'];
    $comment = $affcom['comment'];
    $rating = $affcom['rating'];
    $date = $affcom['date'];

    // Get gravatar Image 
    // https://fr.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/php/
    $default = "mm";
    $size = 35;
    $grav_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/".md5(strtolower(trim($email)))."?d=".$default."&s=".$size;

?>
<div class="cmt-cnt">
    <img src="<?php echo $grav_url; ?>" />
    <div class="thecom">
        <h5><?php echo $name; ?></h5><span data-utime="1371248446" class="com-dt"><?php echo $date; ?></span>
        <br/>
        <p>
            <?php echo $comment; ?>
        </p>
        <p>

           <input type="radio" name="hoi" value="1" <?php echo ($rating=='1')?'checked':'' ?> />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi" value="2" <?php echo ($rating=='2')?'checked':'' ?> />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi" value="3" <?php echo ($rating=='3')?'checked':'' ?> />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi" value="4" <?php echo ($rating=='4')?'checked':'' ?> />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi" value="5" <?php echo ($rating=='5')?'checked':'' ?> />

        </p>
    </div>
</div><!-- end "cmt-cnt" -->
<?php } ?>
```

This is an image of what it looks like right now:

[image]

Can someone tell me how to check all of the boxes (based on database values)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question properly???

If you want to check the radio buttons according to ratting you can use in this way:

```html
<form>
<p>
           <input type="radio" name="hoi1" value="1" checked />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi2" value="2"  />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi3" value="3"  />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi4" value="4" />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi5" value="5"  />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi6" value="5" />
</p>
</form>
<form>
<p>
           <input type="radio" name="hoi1" value="1" checked />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi2" value="2" checked />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi3" value="3"  />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi4" value="4"  />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi5" value="5"  />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi6" value="5"  />
</p>
</form>
<form>
<p>
           <input type="radio" name="hoi1" value="1" checked />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi2" value="2" checked />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi3" value="3" checked />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi4" value="4"  />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi5" value="5"  />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi6" value="5"  />
</p>
</form>
<form>
<p>
           <input type="radio" name="hoi1" value="1" checked />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi2" value="2" checked />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi3" value="3" checked />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi4" value="4" checked />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi5" value="5"  />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi6" value="5"  />
</p>
</form>
<form>
<p>
           <input type="radio" name="hoi1" value="1" checked />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi2" value="2" checked />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi3" value="3" checked />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi4" value="4" checked />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi5" value="5" checked />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi6" value="5"  />
</p>
</form>
<form>
<p>
           <input type="radio" name="hoi1" value="1" checked />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi2" value="2" checked />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi3" value="3" checked />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi4" value="4" checked />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi5" value="5" checked />
           <input type="radio" name="hoi6" value="5" checked />
</p>
</form>
```

Use different names for the tags. And you can put them inside the form tag.

Comment: Hey Dineth thanks for your answer. However, what I want to achieve is that all the radio buttons are checked according to the values that are already stored in the database. For instance, "sds" chose radio button 3, so value 3 is now recorded in the database. But as you can see the 3rd radio button from "ads" is not checked right now,, only the radio button of "dsadh" is checked. My question now is how can all these radio buttons be checked (as all values are in the database)? Now the only one that is checked is the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, fixed it. The name was the problem. It should be unique for every set of radio buttons ;). Tnx for your help Dineth